# Is it possible to subscribe to a lib event on a REST request and wait for a return?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to know if it is possible to subscribe to a third party lib event, which in this case is Microsoft.Speech.dll, because in my attempt, it didnt work, that is, the recognition does not happen and the event is not triggered. I tried using Task and without, but nothing. I don't really know if it's possible to subscribe to an event that way and the request wait it. Follow the code.

```
private string text = string.Empty;

public async Task<string> Get()
{
    var result = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var cmds = new string[] { "cmd 1", "cmd 2", "cmd N" };
        var ci = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
        var sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ci);
        var g = new Choices();
        g.Add(cmds);
        var gb = new GrammarBuilder(g);
        var g = new Grammar(gb);
        sre.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
        sre.LoadGrammarAsync(g);
        sre.SpeechRecognized += Sre_SpeechRecognized;

        sre.SetInputToWaveFile("anyWavfile.wav");
        sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

    });

    await Task.WhenAll(result);

    return text;
}

private void Sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    text += e.Result.Text;
}
```

Comment: You can't do it like that. `result` task completes immediately. You could try to look at `TaskCompletionSource<T>` for a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Michael, but i solved with ManualResetEvent. TaskCompletionSource would be better?

```
private string text = string.Empty;
private ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public string Get()
{
    var result = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //code...

    });

    manualResetEvent.WaitOne();   

    return text;
}

private void Sre_RecognizeCompleted(object sender, RecognizeCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    manualResetEvent.Set();
}

private void Sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    text += e.Result.Text;
}
```